# Coldfusion neo-cron.xml has been modified - when it hasn't been

Tags: coldfusion, cron, scheduled-tasks

We've just upgraded from CF 9 to 9.0.1 (ColdFusion 9 Update 1). We're running on Windows Server 2008.

After the upgrade we noticed on our server that we were getting a lot of these messages in `server.log`:

```
"Information","scheduler-6","10/05/10","12:34:48",,"neo-cron.xml  has been modified . Reloading the service coldfusion.scheduling.CronServiceImpl@c020a"
"Information","scheduler-5","10/05/10","14:54:50",,"neo-cron.xml  has been modified . Reloading the service coldfusion.scheduling.CronServiceImpl@c020a"
"Information","scheduler-8","10/05/10","15:53:51",,"neo-cron.xml  has been modified . Reloading the service coldfusion.scheduling.CronServiceImpl@c020a"
"Information","scheduler-19","10/05/10","16:57:52",,"neo-cron.xml  has been modified . Reloading the service coldfusion.scheduling.CronServiceImpl@c020a"
"Information","scheduler-18","10/05/10","19:12:54",,"neo-cron.xml  has been modified . Reloading the service coldfusion.scheduling.CronServiceImpl@c020a"
"Information","scheduler-4","10/05/10","21:32:56",,"neo-cron.xml  has been modified . Reloading the service coldfusion.scheduling.CronServiceImpl@c020a"
"Information","scheduler-17","10/05/10","22:32:57",,"neo-cron.xml  has been modified . Reloading the service coldfusion.scheduling.CronServiceImpl@c020a"
"Information","scheduler-7","10/06/10","02:15:00",,"neo-cron.xml  has been modified . Reloading the service coldfusion.scheduling.CronServiceImpl@c020a"
"Information","scheduler-10","10/06/10","05:33:06",,"neo-cron.xml  has been modified . Reloading the service coldfusion.scheduling.CronServiceImpl@c020a"
"Information","scheduler-0","10/06/10","06:50:08",,"neo-cron.xml  has been modified . Reloading the service coldfusion.scheduling.CronServiceImpl@c020a"
"Information","scheduler-4","10/06/10","07:33:09",,"neo-cron.xml  has been modified . Reloading the service coldfusion.scheduling.CronServiceImpl@c020a"
"Information","scheduler-15","10/06/10","08:40:10",,"neo-cron.xml  has been modified . Reloading the service coldfusion.scheduling.CronServiceImpl@c020a"
```

We have not touched the `neo-cron.xml` file, but since the upgrade, every few hours CF thinks the file has been changed.

We probably would not have noticed this only for the fact that for a period between 2 of the reloads **all our scheduled tasks were being executed twice**! However, after another reload of `neo-cron.xml` the duplication stopped.

Has anyone else come across this issue?

Thanks in advance.

PS: *Enable logging for scheduled tasks* in CF admin is **not** enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the doubling up of tasks, but I also noticed that `neo-cron.xml` was constantly being modified.

Looks like they've added a new node to each task, `last_run`, which is updated after each execution of a task.

Comment: I might be invalidating the CF warranty (!) but best to mention that we have hacked the `neo-cron.xml` file to run some tasks every 5 seconds. We've never had an issue with this until today. I'm worried that such frequently run tasks might be causing an issue with the `last_run` node updating. I will look into this further.